# Android - Handling a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError produced by Admob

Tags: android, out-of-memory, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I am facing an issue for some specific devices on my Android app, which is originally produced by the Admob banners I use to monetize my app.

The error is produced outside of my code, whithin the Admob SDK, so I have little control over it. I am considering implementing an uncaughtexceptionhandler but I honestly don't know how to do it...or even if it would be a good idea given it is an OutOfMemoryError and chances for recovery are slim, but at least I could use the handler to save the activity status for next execution and minimize the user's lost of progress.

This is a sample of the stack trace, in case someone can help me address the original error, although I acknowledge chances are slim since it is Admob code...

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:     at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:883)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:975)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1393)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.d.execute(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@212104400@212104400000.375149532.375149532:0)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.event.do.w(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@212104400@212104400000.375149532.375149532:0)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.event.fg.br(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@212104400@212104400000.375149532.375149532:0)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.activeview.f.c(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@212104400@212104400000.375149532.375149532:38)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.activeview.b.run(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at asz.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@212104400@212104400000.375149532.375149532:0)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.zzak.a(zzak.java:1)
    at asz.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@212104400@212104400000.375149532.375149532:0)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7356)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Thank you.